# How to install WINE in a linux server using clone method from GitHub?

Tags: linux, hpc

I tried to install by downloading from linux terminal and running the commands

```
$ cd wine-3.0-rc1
$ ./configure --enable-win64
$ make
# make install
```

and gives always error and fail to proceed. Since I am new to linux programming a helping hand to this problem will be appreciated.!

From the long error messages I am pasting the last displayed words

```
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/gokul/SAR/wine-3.0-rc1/dlls/acledit'
STRIPPROG="strip" ./tools/install-sh  dlls/acledit/acledit.dll.so /usr/local/lib64/wine/acledit.dll.so
/bin/sh: ./tools/install-sh: Permission denied
make: *** [dlls/acledit/install-lib] Error 126
```

Comment: 1) What error messages do you receive, and what do they tell you to do? 2) Why do you need the rc1 instead of the real 3.0 release?

Comment: I have added the error in the question. Sorry for not including it.

Comment: Apart from the question of why use rc1, you might need to run it under sudo.

Comment: I don't have sudo access. I am using linux server with individual space provided

Comment: Relevant: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/42567